# Hash sum via pipe, abort if no match

Tags: security, curl, hashsum

How can I verify a checksum of a file by piping it? e.g. I want to do something like

```
curl -sL https://example.org/maybe-safe-maybe-not.tar.gz | md5sum 8da7904f495f682c39fa505b6404f9d1 | tar xvzC /usr/local/bin
```

Where `md5sum` or similar program will abort the pipeline if the given hash (as an arg) doesn't match, or forward the file outputs if it does match.

This would make my scripts a little more secure I think, because I can at least be sure I'm getting the  version I tested with.

---

I can check the sum with a bit of hackery:

```
cat yarn.lock | md5sum -c <(echo 8da7904f495f682c39fa505b6404f9d1 -) --status
```

But I don't know how to forward the output of `yarn.lock` after that.

Answer (score 1):

Download to the file name `maybe-safe-maybe-not.tar.gz` and then:

```
expected_digest='8da7904f495f682c39fa505b6404f9d1'
if [ "${expected_digest} -" = "$(md5sum <maybe-safe-maybe-not.tar.gz)" ]; then
    tar xvzf maybe-safe-maybe-not.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin
else
    echo 'ERROR: ...'
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Was hoping for something a little more compact, that didn't use temp files.

Comment: @mpen I guess that's impossible because you have to read all the data before you can compute the digest.

Comment: Hmm.. that's a good point, I wouldn't be able to stream it through but I could still load the whole thing into a buffer in memory.

Comment: @mpen And that is better than a tmp file (in /dev/shm) how?

Comment: Saves some disk IO. Faster to read from memory than a file. Also saves a bit of wear-and-tear on the disk.

Comment: @mpen That's why I mentioned you can put the tmp file in a RAM disk...

Comment: Oh, is that what `/dev/shm` is? TIL. Thanks :D

Comment: @mpen See `df -hT /dev/shm`